# Change WSO2 publisher and devportal(i.e store) SAML SSO from default API manager to Identity Server

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have setup an environment with WSO2 Identity Server(wso2is-km-5.9.0) on Node 1 and WSO2 Api Manager(wso2am-3.0.0) on Node 2 where Node 1 serves all token related requests.
And my aim is to acheive SSO between all service providers that I on-board to this setup, but in WSO2 API manager(3.0.0) the publisher and devportal are by default SAML integrated with API- manager.
How do I change SSO login of Devportal and Publisher from API-manager to Identity-Server, as the Publisher and Devportal are now using token issued by API-manager and the Service Providers are using token issued by Identity server, therefore SSO is not happening between these entities.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve SSO between saml apps in APIM, you can configure IS as a federated IDP in APIM and do SSO with Identity Server.

Please refer to this document to configure Identity Server as an IDP for SSO https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/Learn/Extensions/SAML2SSO/configuring-identity-server-as-idp-for-sso/